# Prevent half pixels position when apply a percentage based 2D transform in Webkit

Tags: webkit, transform, pixel, blurry

When applying in webkit a 2D transform using a percentage, in this case `translateY(-50%)` it seems that if the object size isn't even, the result will be blurry edges.

Does anybody know how to prevent this effect?

Check [this example](http://codepen.io/mrrocks/pen/fkLuw/), the red background box has top and bottom blurry edges.